# How to add line breaks in gwt-celltable?

Tags: gwt

I want to dispaly a string with line breaks in a gwt-celltable column.How can I do it? Can someone help me.

```
strBuilder.append("line 1 ");
strBuilder.append("line 2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
strBuilder.append("line 1").append("</br>");
strBuilder.append("line 2");
```

Comment: Thanks.But I already tried this. But it ignores </br>. It shows like "line 1 line 2"